# I made a navigation plugin in Intellij Idea, but sync now did not appear in the upper right corner

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I made a navigation plugin from the android developer site for the Intellij idea.build.gradle.kts file. I added the .def section to the val and put parentheses at the beginning and end of the quotation marks, but sync now did not appear at the top right.

I wrote a lot of places, today he told me to create a folder and open an xml file and write code in it, I did it, but there was navigation at the beginning and end of the code and it gave an error. I went to the navigation section from the resource manager, but it says navigation is not available, so there was nothing I tried.

Comment: Might want to have a read here: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.